# HDD+SSD on notebook Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I recently bought a notebook with HDD+SSD, Ubuntu came installed on SSD part and I only have access to this. The HDD I can not access.

My main concern is, when I want to save any file on the HD I can not find it, I've already use the gparted and could format it, I formated as fat32, ext4 and ntfs but in any format I could enable it to save file in it.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your HDD mounted? on a GUI it should be as easy as just clicking on the HDD in a Filebrowser

Answer (score 1):

After you formatted it did you actually mount it? Here's what I would do, presuming the device is listed as `/dev/sdb` in an `fdisk -l` output. Also, I am going to presume you want it mounted to `/HDD` (change this to whatever you want).

**Open up a Terminal**

```
sudo -s  # Switch to admin
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb
mkdir /HDD
nano /etc/fstab  # Use VIM if you don't have nano
```

Insert the following line at the end of the file:

```
/dev/sdb1 /HDD auto defaults 0 0
```

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> then <kbd>Y</kbd> to save and exit

```
mount -a  # To verify the drive mounts as /HDD
```

**Close Terminal**

Open your File Explorer, navigate to your root folder (/), find `HDD`. Right-click and Send to > Side Pane (create shortcut).

Now, reboot the system. Your drive should auto mount and be on the side pane.

**Change Permissions**

The following command will give full permissions to all users for a drive. Look at [the wiki page about file permissions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions) for information on what each 7 does and if you wanted to do anything different.

```
sudo chmod +777 -R /HDD
```

Comment: One more thing, now I can see the HD and it start already mounted, but I can not save anything due no permission, Do you know how to remove the admin rights on the HD?

Comment: Providing you mounted it as /HDD, run this command.....     sudo chmod +777 -R /HDD    I also edited my original answer to reflect the permissions as well.